# Slow performance of nested loop in R

Tags: r, performance, xts, stock

I have a xts series consisting of 250 observations and 584 columns. I am running a nested for loop on this series. This nested loops takes too much time. I have tried to create a reproducible example. On actual data set nested loop is taking too much time. Please suggest some efficient ways to do the same nested loop

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(xts)
library(zoo)
## dataset
bsereturn<-managers
##### calculating bse_lag
bse_lag<-head(bsereturn,-1)

## calculating bse forward
bse_forward<-tail(bsereturn,-1)

## defining look back and skip period
s=12
k=1
## Empty xts to store looping results
XSMOM = bse_lag
XSMOM[1:nrow(XSMOM),1:ncol(XSMOM)] <- NA
# Compute Momentum
system.time(for (i in 1:ncol(bse_lag)){
  
  for (t in (s + 1):nrow(bse_lag)){
    XSMOM[t,i] =  Return.cumulative(bse_lag[(t-s):(t-1-k),i])
    
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results in your example look weird to me. The return you have for 1997-01-31 is the cumulative return for 1996-01-31 through 1996-11-30. Why do you ignore the return from 1996-12-31?

Anyway, you use `rollapply` to get your answer. Your example runs ~4x faster for me than the single loop in Jerome's answer.

```r
# this is what I would do
xsmom <- lag(rollapplyr(1 + bsereturn, 11, prod) - 1)
# this is what you have (lagged 2 periods)
xsmom2 <- lag(rollapplyr(1 + bsereturn, 11, prod) - 1, 2)
```

Comment: Ulrich Sir I do this purposefully. Actually I am replicating momentum strategies, following the literature there must be 1 month gap between formation and holding period to avoid microstructure biases.

Comment: I agree there should be a 1-month gap. You have a 2-month gap. As of the end of January 1997, your results suggest you can only make a decision using data through the end of November, 1996.  It is like saying that you can only use data through the end of May in order to make an investment decision at the end of this month. Why would you ignore data from June when it's available?

Comment: sir, I am getting this error when I apply xsmom. Error in c.xts(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
  zero-length vectors with non-zero-length index are not allowed

Comment: @sim235 just apply lag.xts instead of lag only.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks Sir, you saved me. I was making crucial error

Comment: @sim235: you're welcome, happy to help. Regarding your error: you have `dplyr` loaded, and it masks the `stats::lag()` generic function that ships with base R. That breaks method dispatch for all S3 classes that define a `lag()` method.

Answer (score 1):

R loops are insanely slow. You can compute the cumulative return on multiple columns at the same time:

```r
system.time(
    for (t in (s + 1):nrow(bse_lag)){
        XSMOM[t,1:ncol(bse_lag)] =  Return.cumulative(bse_lag[(t-s):(t-1-k),1:ncol(bse_lag)])
    }
)
```

This is about 5 times faster on my machine.

I think you can compute the cumulative return efficiently in an incremental way too (thus about `s=12` times faster), but probably not directly in R.